# How to get rid of use absolute urls error when trying to async action creators in React?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, redux, fetch

I keep getting the error that I need to use absolute URL's from `fetch` when I am trying to mock the test call with `fetchMock` and `nock`.

```
describe('fetchFileNames creator @AT-fetchTodosIfNeeded@', () => {
    it('should create RECEIVE_FILE_NAMES_SUCCESS after the fetching is done', () => {

        const fileNames = ['testFile1', 'testFile2', 'testFile3'];
        const expectedActions = [
            { type: ac.REQUEST_FILE_NAMES },
            { type: ac.RECEIVE_FILE_NAMES_SUCCESS, fileNames }
        ];
        const store = mockStore({
            files: {
                fileNames
            }
        });

        fetchMock.get('*', { files: fileNames});

        return store.dispatch(at.fetchFileNames())
            .then(() => {
                var createdActions = store.getActions();
                delete createdActions[1].receivedAt;
                expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions);
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code turned out to be okay.  I was importing `isomorphic-fetch` incorrectly into the async action creators file. What I was doing: `import fetch from isomorphic-fetch` what I should have been doing: `import isomorphic-fetch`.  It's documented in `fetch-mock`, but I missed it and this was getting frustrating.